# What is the better way of handling HTTP responce statuses?

Tags: java, android

```
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201){

    }
    .....
```

I have different statuses and I need to handle all them to show later for appropriate status appropriate dialog message.

What is the better way of handling HTTP response statuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is as follows:

1. Put these status codes and corresponding messages in a property file. 
   Your could do something like
   staus_201= Message for status 201
2. When you receive a status, retrieve the corresponding message from the property files ([see example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html) )and display them.
3. The **advantage** of this is: for any new status, you won't have to do any code change. Just add the new entry in property file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `switch case`

```
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

switch(status){
  case 201 : //do something ;
             break;

  so on...

  default : //do something else;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest to use [symbolic names](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) instead of "magic values" things like this:

```
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == HttpServletResponseCode.SC_CREATED) {
  ...
}
```

In this case it's really doesn't matter if you use if or a switch-case...but most important the code will be more readable by using symbolic names. (I'm not sure which library you are using...i assume every library will have such kind of constants like [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpStatus.html).).